# how to solve this exception in Neo4j?

Tags: exception, neo4j

thanks for reading my problem,may you help me to solve this problem.
at first time,it will be ok,but when it finish, I do the same thing,It occurped this exception:

```
org.neo4j.graphdb.TransactionFailureException: Database is currently not available. No blocking components
at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.beginTx(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:942)
at org.neo4j.kernel.TransactionBuilderImpl.begin(TransactionBuilderImpl.java:43)
at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.beginTx(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:935)
at com.myapplication.dao.DataOperation.getUser(DataOperation.java:77)
at com.myapplication.dao.DataOperation.createRelationShip(DataOperation.java:205)
at com.myapplication.business.UploadData.upload(UploadData.java:29)
at com.myapplication.servlet.UploadServlet.doPost(UploadServlet.java:96)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

but all my operations to change the database are in a transction like demo

```
try (Transaction tx = graphDB.beginTx()) {
        //do something
        tx.success();
    }
```

How do I use Neo4j connections like MySQL connections?

my environment is Eclipse + Tomcat 7.0 in Java 7
and this is the link of database log https://www.dropbox.com/s/a7858mywidbvr03/messages.log
thank you very much

Comment: Seems like your database is blocked after the execution. Maybe you start the same progress again, before the locks on the db are released? You need to provide us with more detailed information.

Comment: thank you very much. all my operation are in a transaction like this   try (Transaction tx = graphDB.beginTx()) so I don't konw how to do……

Comment: Do you have a cluster of Neo4j instances or just one?

Comment: yes, just one instance. I don't know how to use Neo4j instances like MySQL's connections,have you some demo? thank you very much.

Comment: Do you run it in HA mode? Could you share your data/graph.db/messages.log e.g. via dropbox, pastebin or github gist?

Comment: No, I just do it on my computer as my homework. and my environment is Eclipse 3.2 + Tomcat 7.0, it is a embed database. Thank you very much.

Comment: this is the link of my log.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/a7858mywidbvr03/messages.log   thank you very much